# Data binding in React

Tags: reactjs

What I want to do is when I type some text in an input field, it should appear in another place realtime.

Below is my input;

```html
<div className="post_input">
    <input className='post_data_input_overlay' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt"/>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This part is quite vague ```it should appear in another place realtime```.
Where do you want it to appear?

Comment: @FreedomPride in the same page

Comment: It's now possible with hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59062963/7224430

Comment: [Simple Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/OJPYWNw) explains it best

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Data binding in React can be achieved by using a `controlled input`. A controlled input is achieved by binding the value to a `state variable` and a `onChange` event to change the state as the input value changes.

See the below snippet

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { value: 'Hello World' };
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

### Update: React Hooks

Here is an equivalent function component of the class defined above.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('Hello World');
  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @vsync the handleChange method is written using an arrow function and arrow functions get the context from their parent which in this case is the react component class

Comment: This is not efficient, the arrow function is dynamic and when transpiled gets moved to the object constructor and not the prototype. So N instances of the component will generate N functions, instead of 1. Ideally you should bind in the constructor, although this is more verbose.

Comment: @jfeferman, yes you are right. Although this is more verbose and doesn't make much of a performance difference untill a huge amount of class instances are created

Comment: @jfeferman what about `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`, we can use this instead of binding it in the constructor

Comment: @Omu, yes you can do that, but its not very performant since it creates a new function on every render. binding in constructor is the preferred pattern

Comment: It is less boilerplate with React useState hook. See the example below in my answer

Comment: Check the other answer, which uses plain function and hooks instead of a class to achieve the same.

Comment: So, if I have a form with 6 fields, I should provide 6 different handler functions for it?

Comment: @mimic, no not necessarily. You could have one handler which is passed the key which it use to update the state. Please refer this post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153058/single-handler-for-multiple-input-elements-in-react/47153965#47153965

Answer (score 27):

To be short, in React, there's no two-way data-binding.

So when you want to implement that feature, try define a `state`, and write like this, listening events, update the state, and React renders for you:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Details here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

**UPDATE 2020**

> **Note**:
>
> LinkedStateMixin is deprecated as of React v15. The recommendation is
>   to explicitly set the value and change handler, instead of using
>   LinkedStateMixin.

above update from React official [site](https://reactjs.org/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) . Use below code if you are running under v15 of React else **don't**.

There are actually people wanting to write with two-way binding, but React does not work in that way. If you do want to write like that, you have to use an addon for React, like this:

```
var WithLink = React.createClass({
  mixins: [LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState('message')} />;
  }
});
```

Details here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

For `refs`, it's just a solution that allow developers to reach the DOM in methods of a component, see here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: so how can I show the updated value in my new text field?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD say your text field is `<span>`, just use `<span>{this.state.value}</span>`. React renders it based on `this.state`, and inside `{}` it's a JavaScript expression.

Comment: Downvoted. Your first sentence comes across as condescending and distracts from what's important - the answer.

Comment: @ncubica @ Yoshiyahu You can edit the answer as you want. I'm already give up answering questions since SO is such an unfriendly community. Disappointed.

Comment: @jiyinyiyong Thanks for the edit! Sorry if I came across as rude. Downvote retracted.

Comment: @jiyinyiyong no worries. I hope you don't stop answering questions. People don't mean to seem rude, but I think we can all get better at making sure our answers, questions and comments are worded thoughtfully.

Comment: In the input tag,  value={this.state.value} is not neccesary right?

Comment: @AkhilV this is too old. LinkedStateMixin has been deprecated for long.

Answer (score 18):

With introduction of [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) the state management (including forms state) became very simple and, in my opinion, way more understandable and predictable comparing with magic of other frameworks. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('some initial value');
    return <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />;
}
```

This one-way flow makes it trivial to understand how the data is updated and when rendering happens. Simple but powerful to do any complex stuff in predictable and clear way. In this case, do "two-way" form state binding.

The example uses the primitive string value. Complex state management, eg. objects, arrays, nested data, can be managed this way too, but it is easier with help of libraries, like [Hookstate](https://github.com/avkonst/hookstate) (Disclaimer: I am the author of this library). Here is [the example of complex state management](https://hookstate.netlify.com/local-complex-from-documentation).

When a form grows, there is an issue with rendering performance: form state is changed (so rerendering is needed) on every keystroke on any form field. This issue is also addressed by Hookstate. Here is the example of [the form with 5000 fields](https://hookstate.netlify.com/performance-demo-large-form): the state is updated on every keystore and there is no performance lag at all.

Answer (score 6):

To bind a control to your state you need to call a function on the component that updates the state from the control's event handler.

Rather than have an update function for all your form fields, you could create a generic update function using ES6 computed name feature and pass it the values it needs inline from the control like this:

```js
class LovelyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  alert("Construct");
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      field1: "Default 1",
      field2: "Default 2"
    };
  }

  update = (name, e) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <p><input type="text" value={this.state.field1} onChange={(e) => this.update("field1", e)} />
          {this.state.field1}</p>
        <p><input type="text" value={this.state.field2} onChange={(e) => this.update("field2", e)} />
          {this.state.field2}</p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<LovelyForm/>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: How do you set the state with typescript

Answer (score 5):

## January 2022

Using hooks you can write a custom component which does exactly what you want.

I used TypeScript in the example below:

```
// InputBind.tsx

import {useState} from 'react';

export interface Binder {
    value: string;
    setter: (value: string) => void;
}

/**
 * Hook that returns a value to be used with InputBind component.
 */
export function useBind(initialValue: string): Binder {
    const [value, setter] = useState(initialValue);
    return {value, setter};
}

/**
 * Custom input component with binding.
 */
export function InputBind({value}: {value: Binder}) {
    return <input type="text" value={value.value}
        onChange={e => value.setter(e.target.value)} />;
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
import {InputBind, useBind} from './InputBind';

function Foo() {
    const name = useBind('john');

    console.log('Value is', name.value);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>The name is {name.value}.</div>
            <InputBind value={name} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The example above is very simple. The concept can be expanded to other `input` types and `select`s as well.

Answer (score 4):

> This could be achieved with a hook. However, I would not recommend it, as it strictly couples state and layout.

## November 2019 Data Bind with Hooks

```js
const useInput = (placeholder, initial) => {
    const [value, setVal] = useState(initial)
    const onChange = (e) => setVal(e.target.value)
    const element = <input value={value} onChange={onChange} placeholder={placeholder}/>
    return {element, value}
}
```

Use it in any functional component

```js
const BensPlayGround = () => {
    const name = useInput("Enter name here")
    return (
        <>
            {name.element}
            <h1>Hello {name.value}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

### Basic version - bind value and onChange

```js
const useDataBind = () => {
    const [value, setVal] = useState("")
    const onChange = (e) => setVal(e.target.value)
    return {value, onChange}
}

const Demo = (props) => {
    const nameProps = useDataBind()
    return (
        <>
            <input {...nameProps} placeholder="Enter name here" />
            <h1>Hello {nameProps.value}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: `This could be achieved with a hook. However, I would not recommend it, as it strictly couples state and layout.` that sounds weird since in any way, you couple layout controls with your component state.

Answer (score 2):

With the new feature called Hooks from the React team which makes functional components to handle state changes.. your question can be solved easily

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Demo = props =>{
    const [text, setText] = useState("there");
    return props.logic(text, setText);
};

const App = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("hello");

    const componentDidMount = () =>{
        setText("hey");
    };
    useEffect(componentDidMount, []);

    const logic = (word, setWord) => (
        <div>
            <h1>{word}</h1>
            <input type="text" value={word} onChange={e => setWord(e.target.value)}></input>
            <h1>{text}</h1>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>
    );
    return <Demo logic={logic} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Define state attributes. Add universal handleChange event handler. Add name param to input tag for mapping.

```
this.state = { stateAttrName:"" }

handleChange=(event)=>{
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value });
  } 

<input className="form-control" name="stateAttrName" value= 
{this.state.stateAttrName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value : ''}
  }
  handleChange = (e) =>{ 
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <div>{this.state.value}</div>
    </div>
   )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> There are actually people wanting to write with two-way binding, but React does not work in that way.

That's true, there are people who want to write with two-way data binding. And there's nothing fundamentally wrong with React preventing them from doing so. I wouldn't recommend them to use deprecated React mixin for that, though. Because it looks so much better with some [third-party packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valuelink).

```
import { LinkedComponent } from 'valuelink'

class Test extends LinkedComponent {
    state = { a : "Hi there! I'm databinding demo!" };

    render(){
        // Bind all state members...
        const { a } = this.linkAll();

        // Then, go ahead. As easy as that.
        return (
             <input type="text" ...a.props />
        )
    }
}
```

The thing is that the two-way data binding is the design pattern in React. [Here's my article with a 5-minute explanation on how it works](https://medium.com/@gaperton/managing-state-and-forms-with-react-part-1-12eacb647112)

Answer (score 0):

Some modules makes simpler data-binding in forms, for example:

react-distributed-forms

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    first_name: "George"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form binding={this}>
        <Input name="first_name" />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-distributed-forms#data-binding

It uses React context, so you don't have to wire together input in forms

[Here's a live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jy3x6xpx4)

Answer (score 0):

### Don't need to Break head with setState() in react.js

A new library made by me [React-chopper](https://github.com/pawarvijay/react-chopper)

Code Like **angularjs** in **reactjs**

Code without **setState** in **reactjs**

Go through **examples** for more description

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Rcp from 'react-chopper';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
    this.modal = Rcp(this.state, this);
  }

  tank = () => {
    console.log(this.modal)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.modal.name} onChange={e => this.modal.name = e.target.value} />
        <p> Bang Bang {this.modal.name} </p>
        <button onClick={() => this.tank()}>console</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comments , Pr Are welcome ...Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I think @Richard Garside is correct.

I suggest some changes to clear even more the code.

Change this

```
onChange={(e) => this.update("field2", e)}
```

To this

```
onChange={this.handleOnChange}
```

And also, change this

```
this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value });
```

To this

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```

Besides, you have to add the "name" attribute to the field with a value that relates with the key on the state object.